# office js shared runtime where to find logging statements and stacktraces? Not in browser console

Tags: javascript, excel, logging, office-js, office-addins

I am exploring the office-js API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-debugging outlines that for a shared js browser runtime logs or stack traces should be explorable from the browser developer tools.

However, for me this is not the case.

to demonstrate:

```
/**
 * Calculates the volume of a sphere.
 * @customfunction
 * @param {number} radius
 * @returns The volume of the sphere.
 */
function sphereVolume(radius) {
  console.log('*** called here ***');

  return (Math.pow(radius, 3) * 4 * Math.PI) / 3;
}
```

one of the default examples (running either in scriptlab or the yeoman yo office scaffolded project) has been modified for some logging statements:

```
console.log('*** called here ***');
```

however, even though the function correctly returns back the computed value to the UI I am unable to find the logs in any console.

Where are these logs hidden? How can I find these (if not in the developer`s toolbar/console?

### edit

a shared runtime is requested

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

Comment: Do you see log lines to the console if the shared runtime is not used?

Comment: true - when switching the runtime I can see logs

Comment: Then I'd suggest posting this as an issue to the [OfficeJS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I just tested using my setup w/ Visual Studio 2017 and I saw the console log when running a custom function.

Comment: Can you share your Dev Setup? I'm guessing VSCode, but just to confirm/share

Comment: Tested using your function as well and it showed logs. But again, I'm using a different Dev setup I'm thinking.

Comment: Try uninstalling "Edge WebView Runtime 2" perhaps? Just to see, I know my Dev setup breaks w/ it installed (no console), but my Add-In continues to work.

Comment: It is VSCode - but I was running from outside VSCode i.e. via the terminal and the npm run tasks.

Comment: I am running on osx - I do not have any edge runtime platform.